# transparent background color for Ti.UI.currentWindow

Tags: android, titanium

How can I set background color for  Ti.UI.currentWindow ?

I used this code but it does not work:

```
var curtWind = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
curtWind.backgroundColor = '#00FFFFFF';
```

I used also:

```
curtWind.backgroundColor= 'transparent';
```

Also with function setBackground it does not work.

Any idea

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the backgroundColor property to null